# PHP: access to method of object with private constructor

Tags: php

I have a class:

```
class A
{
    private function __construct()
    {
        throw new Exception('thrown');
    }

    public function A()
    {
        return array('a', 'b', 'c');
    }

    public static function I()
    {
        return new A();
    }
}
```

Question: how can I print on screen exactly that 'b' from array above?
Conditions:
I can't alter this class.
I can use only one command (at least one line in code)

Comment: Why do you have this class in the first place? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As you cannot instantiate the class at all, and can't call the A() method statically, you can't access anything in your class, making it pretty useless for anything

Comment: You could probably bypass these issues using reflection, but the class is still basically useless

Comment: `echo (new ReflectionClass('A'))->newInstanceWithoutConstructor()->A()[1];`

Comment: Just extend the class and add a public constructor to the child class. And call the method as usual.

Comment: Mark Baker, you are awesome! Your answer with ReflectionClass is exactly what was needed!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass("A");
$instance = $reflection->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
```

use methods of A class over `$instance`.